# Update Object Reference

Tags: c#

I have a List which contains some User-Objects. For example:

```
public List<User> Users { get; } = new List<User>
(
    new User
    {
        Username = "Marvin",
        IsAdmin = true
    },
    new User
    {
        Username = "John",
        IsAdmin = false
    }
);
```

Now lets say I want to edit the user John and I want him to be an admin as well.

```
User john = Users.First(x => x.Username == "John");
```

Because I only want the changes to be applied when I hit save, I won't edit the actual object itself. Instead I create a clone one to work with the object until it has been saved by the user.

```
User johnClone = (User)john.Clone();
```

When I hit save, all changes from the clone object should be applied to the main object. But I do not want to do it for every property by myself. For example:

```
john.IsAdmin = johnClone.IsAdmin;
```

Instead I want to update the entire reference of the object to the new one. So I won't need to update the properties by hand and within every other class which has john assigned to will be updated automatically.

I think this needs to be achived with pointers. But does anyone of you know how to do this?

I allready tried to update the item within the List itself like this:

```
int index = Users.IndexOf(john);
Users[index] = johnClone;
```

But this doesn't update the instances which asked for the user John before it was updated.

Comment: I don't understand the *"I only want the changes to be applied when I hit save"* requirement. What "save" are you hitting and why does it prevent you from modifying objects in memory? Usually saving implies writing things to some kind of permanent storage

Comment: What do you mean by "instances which asked for the user John before it was updated"?

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm using a Blazor Server Application. This passes the object to another component to allow the user to change the data. The data of the object is used within both the page and the edit component. When I change the original value on the passed object, it automatically refreshes the data on the page. But this would also appen when the user cancels the editing. The changes will stay in memory then until the user reloads the page. Because of this I create a copy of the object and rewrite their properties when it was saved in the DB.

Comment: @mbd with this I mean when I assign the object to a property of another class. For example. Think of a class which has a property of type user which gets set in the constructor. I want this property being updated the new object once I apply my edited object to my collection.

Answer (score 0):

Does your user object implement some kind of clone or copy method? you could implement a clone/copy method which creates a new user object to keep a separate user object with different values and apply the clone/copy to the original when your save button is pressed. Note that you should use a new object for this.

possible implementation of clone function

```
public User Copy()
{
    return new User
    {
         Username = this.UserName,
         IsAdmin = this.IsAdmin
    }
 }
```

then edit the copy as following

```
User copy = jhon.Copy();
copy.IsAdmin = true;
```

Comment: This is my problem. I'm already doing a copy of my object. But I'm looking to exchange the base object with the edited object without mapping every property by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the an example which creates a list type and uses `ref` to play as a pointer in the managed world.

```
public class RefUserList : IEnumerable
{
    private User[] _list = new User[100];
    private int _p;

    public void Add(User user)
        => _list[_p++] = user;

    public ref User this[int index]
        => ref _list[index];

    public void SetUser(int index, User user)
    {
        ref var u = ref this[index];
        u = user;
        _list[index] = user;
    }

    public ref User SearchUser(string name)
        => ref this[Array.FindIndex(_list, u => u.Username == name)];

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The cons is you cannot use LINQ (to find a user), take a look at the `SearchUser` method, the reason is LINQ doesn't return a ref type. Also get and set indexer are not available at the same time.

To use this list, you have to keep the return value as a ref type in every place.

```
Users.Add(new User { Username = "John", IsAdmin = false });

ref User u = ref Users.SearchUser("John");
Console.WriteLine($"{u.Username} {u.IsAdmin});
//John false
```

Now replace the element with a new user, the variable is also got updated.

```
Users.SetUser(0, new User { Username = "Peter", IsAdmin = true });
Console.WriteLine($"{u.Username} {u.IsAdmin});
//Peter true
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to wrap the user class and use a proxy object.
internal class Program

```
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var repository = new UserRepository();
        var john = repository.Users.First(x => x.Name == "John");
        var johnClone = (User)john.Clone();
        johnClone.IsAdmin = true;
        john.Refresh(johnClone);
    }
}
public sealed class UserRepository
{
    public UserRepository()
    {
        Users = new List<User>()
{
    new User
    {
        Name = "Marvin",
        IsAdmin = true
    },
    new User
    {
        Name = "John",
        IsAdmin = false
    }
};
    }

    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public sealed class User : ICloneable
{
    public User()
    {
        _user = this;
    }

    private readonly object _sync = new object();

    private User _user;
    

    private string _name;
    private bool _isAdmin;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _user._name;
        set => _user._name = value;
    }
    public bool IsAdmin
    {
        get => _user._isAdmin;
        set => _user._isAdmin = value;
    }

    public void Refresh(User user)
    {
        if (user == null)
            return;

        lock (_sync)
        {
            _user = user;
        }
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new User()
        {
            Name = this.Name,
            IsAdmin = this.IsAdmin
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working but it creates much boilerplate code for getters and setters. Could you tell me what the _sync and lock is good for?

Comment: if you have multithreading in your code it guarantees the order of changes

Answer (score 0):

This is working as you expected. I created a class User implementing Clone(); then another class MetaUser with a property of type List of Users, then instantiated and filled a list of users (myListOfUsers), asign it to a MetaUser object (myAnotherObjectReferencedToMyList), cloned one item from the original list (john), modified its IsAdmin property to true, and overwrote the original object from the list with the cloned and modified one. The second item in myAnotherObjectReferencedToMyList updated as expected with IsAdmin to true.

User class:

```
public class User : ICloneable
{
    public String Username { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsAdmin { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        Object retorno = new User()
        {
            Username = this.Username,
            IsAdmin = this.IsAdmin
        };
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

MetaUser class:

```
public class MetaUser
    {
        public List<User> MetaUserUsers { get; set; }

        public MetaUser(List<User> newUsers) {
            this.MetaUserUsers = newUsers;        
        }
    }
```

Test:

```
public void myTest() 
{ 
// Original list of users
        List<User> myListOfUsers = new List<User>() { new User()    {
            Username = "Marvin",
            IsAdmin = true
            },
            new User()
            {
                Username = "John",
                IsAdmin = false
            }};

        MetaUser myAnotherObjectReferencedToMyList = new MetaUser(myListOfUsers);

        User john = myAnotherObjectReferencedToMyList.MetaUserUsers.First(x => x.Username == "John");
        User johnClone = (User)john.Clone();
        johnClone.IsAdmin = true;

        int myIndex = myListOfUsers.IndexOf(john);

        myListOfUsers[myIndex] = johnClone;
        //  myAnotherObjectReferencedToMyList.MetaUserUsers[1].IsAdmin is true now

    }
```